# Initialize state with dynamic key based on props in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects, computed-properties

How to initialize state with dynamic key based on props? The props is a data fetched from external source (async). So the props will change when the data is succesfully downloaded. Consider a component like this.

edit: I want to make the state dynamic because I want to generate a dialog (pop up) based on the item that is clicked. the `DialogContainer` is basically that. `visible` prop will make that dialog visible, while `onHide` prop will hide that dialog. I use [react-md library](https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/dialogs).

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    // the key and value will be dynamically generated, with a loop on the props
    // something like:
    for (const item of this.props.data) {
      this.state[`dialog-visible-${this.props.item.id}`] = false}
    }
  }

  show(id) {
    this.setState({ [`dialog-visible-${id}`]: true });
  }

  hide(id) {
    this.setState({ [`dialog-visible-${id}`]: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div key={item.id} onClick={this.show(item.id)}>
                <h2> Show Dialog on item-{item.id}</h2>
              </div>
              <DialogContainer
                visible={this.state[`dialog-visible-${item.id}`]}
                onHide={this.hide(item.id)}
              >
                <div>
                  <h1> A Dialog that will pop up </h1>
                </div>
              </DialogContainer>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// the data is fetched by other component.
class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // fetchData come from redux container (mapDispatchToProps)
    this.props.fetchData('https://someUrlToFetchJSONData/')
  }
}
```

The data then is shared via Redux.

However, based on my understanding so far, state can be updated based on props with `componentWillReceiveProps` or the new `getDerivedStateFromProps` (not on the constructor as above). But, how to do that on either method?

The example [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#updating-state-based-on-props) only explains when the state is initialized on the constructor, and call `setState` on either cWRP or gDSFP. But, I want the key value pair to be initialized dynamically.

Any help/hint will be greatly appreciated. Please do tell if my question is not clear enough.

Comment: when you run the `for loop` in constructor, is the `props.data` supposed to be provided by redux?

Comment: yes. That is the case.

Comment: And you want to use the state provided by redux. That's what you are asking right?

Comment: Not directly. I've added some details. Let me first understand your answer. 
edit: I understand how to connect state with connect(). But I want to generate another state with the information from that data. Not directly. 

Thanks!

Comment: why can't you have the states created as you want them to be in the action itself? Then you can just map them through `render()` function

Comment: and in terms of clicking and showing data, that can be another state of itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {yourAction} from '../your/action/path';

class YourClass extends React.Component {
    state = {};

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.yourAction()
    }

    render() {
        const {data} = this.props; //your data state from redux is supplied as props.

        return (
            <div>
                {!data ? '' : data.map(item => (
                    <div>{item}</div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return{
        data:state.data //state.data if that is how it is referred to in the redux. Make sure you apply the correct path of state within redux
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {yourAction})(YourClass)
```

If you do this, `<div>{item}</div>` will change as you change the data state. The idea is to just map the redux state to your class props - you don't have to map the props back to the state. The `render()` automatically listens to changes in props supplied by `redux`. However, if you do want to somehow know `redux` state change in events, you can add the following functions.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    console.log(newProps)
}

getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    console.log(nextProps);
    console.log(prevState);
}
```